# Replace variable num in double quotes - SED

Tags: sed

I have a line like this:

```
"abc/x-y-z": "^1.4"
```

I need to replace `^1.4`with `*` in the same file such that the output is `"abc/x-y-z": "*"`
The num inside the double quotes could be any variable number.

I tried this but it is highly specific to `^1.4` number:

```
sed -i '21s/^1.4/*/' abc.json
```

Comment: `^` is the start anchor in regexp, must be escaped `\^`, and also `.` which means any character

Comment: If this is version dependencies, for example in a package.json file, you might have multiple dots in the version: `"@babel/cli": "^7.2.3"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your shown samples, please try following. You need to escape `^` here to make it literal character and you need to escape `.` dot as well to make it treat as literal character.

```
sed 's/\^1\.4/*/' Input_file
```

OR as per OP's comment to make it dynamic try:

```
sed 's/\^[0-9]+\.[0-9]+/*/' Input_file
```

Also if you are performing it on 21st line of your file then use `21s` like you tried in your attempt. This code will substitute only very 1st occurrence of ^1.4 here in case you want to substitute all occurrences then use `g`(globally substitution) option for above code.

I have not used `-i` option(to do inplace update into Input_file itself) once you are happy with results then use `sed -i` option in above code.

Comment: @Snk, oh ok try `sed 's/\^[0-9]\.[0-9]/*/' Input_file` then once and let me know if this helps you?

Comment: + is just a literal in BREs like sed uses.

Answer (score 3):

When making changes to files, I prefer the file editor `ed` to the stream editor  `sed` (`ed` is standard, `sed -i` isn't, and different versions have different quirks that bite people here on a regular basis).

```sh
ed -s input.txt <<EOF
21s/"^[[:digit:]]\{1,\}\(\.[[:digit:]]\{1,\}\)\{0,1\}"/"*"/
w
EOF
```

On line 21, matches a quote followed by a carat followed by 1 or more digits, optionally followed by a period and another sequence of 1 or more digits and finally the trailing quote character. All that is replaced by `"*"`, and finally the changed file is **w**ritten back to disk.

Posix BREs are a pain, no? GNU `ed` 1.17 and newer, and NetBSD `ed` can take EREs instead:

```sh
ed -Es input.txt <<EOF
21s/"\^[[:digit:]]+(\.[[:digit:]]+)?"/"*"/
w
EOF
```

which is a lot easier to read.

Comment: I'm aware of the irony in complaining about a non-standard `sed` extension and then giving an answer that uses a non-standard `ed` extension, yes.